# Error con el modulo speech_recognition en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, librería, audio

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de cómo hacer un asistente virtual con Python, pero tengo problemas al importar el módulo speech_recognition.

He probado a hacer lo siguiente:

1. `pppip install SpeechRecognition`
2. `pip3 install speechrecognition`
3. `pipwin install speechrecognition`

En todas me dice que el módulo ya está instalado:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\%User%\Desktop\api-s\jarvis\jarvis.py", line 4, in <module>
    import speech_recognition as sr # pip install SpeechRecognition
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
```

Mi versión de Python, la cual trabajo en VSCode, es la 3.9.6, aquí el log:

```
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Y cuando vuelvo a tratar de instalar SpeechRecognition me sale este log:

```
Requirement already satisfied: SpeechRecognition in c:\users\%user%\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages 
(3.8.1)
```

Asumo que es un problema de versiones el cual no se cómo solucionar. Pero quizá esté asumiendo mal. Igualmente no se qué hacer.

¿Una ayudita?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tienes un problema de versiones.

La librería `SpeechRecognition` hizo su última actualización el 5 de diciembre de 2017, esto se puede ver en el [*release history* de Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/#history)

Por otro lado en la misma página puedes ver los lenguajes de programación que soporta, y la versión más moderna que aparece es `Python 3.6`, mientras que tu estás intentando usarlo en `Python 3.9`

**Las soluciónes son,** crearte un entorno con `Python 3.6` o utilizar otra librería más actualizada.

### Bonus

`Python 3.9.6` ha salido el 28 de junio de 2021, es decir hace diez días. Las librerías de Python son la mayoría Open source, por lo que son personas que **voluntariamente de forma gratuita crean y mantienen las librerías.** Estoy seguro de que ningún paquete habrá adaptado toda la librería a la última versión de Python, de hecho, **la mayoría tardan entre varios meses y un año** en actualizarse a nuevas versiones. **Tener la última versión de Python solo te va a dar problemas de compatibilidad**, salvo que tengas un motivo y sepas muy bien lo que estás haciendo (hagas lo que hagas instala siempre una versión anterior para evitarlo python 3.8).

Comment: Vale, muchísimas gracias, creía que el 3.8.1 era la versión del SpeechRecognition. Esta noche intentaré poner el entorno de python 3.6

Comment: He editado la pregunta, porque llevas razón, 3.8.1 es la versión de `SpeechRecognition` el problema es por el primero!